# I need to run a rails command on deployment, but just once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have installed the gem "devise_security_extension" in my project to limit one session per user.

In this gem installation process I had to run the command "rails generate devise_security_extension:install".

Now I'd like to know the best way to deploy my new feature to production without I have to run this command on server manually.

I use capistrano on production server, so is there a way to run this command only if my "Devise security extension install" commit is being deployed? For previous or next commits this command would be ignored.

Comment: I would run this command locally, commit the changes it made and deploy application as usual

Comment: Sorry. It was a stupid question. This command only create some files.